# Multiple jQuery UI Sliders on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm having a real difficult time implementing multiple jQuery UI sliders on the same page. Everytime I move any of the sliders, the content items from all sliders slide instead of just the one positioned below the items I want to slide.

Example:

```
<!--Box 1-->
<div class="scroll-pane">
<div class="scroll-content">
  <ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<!--Box 2-->
<div class="scroll-pane">
<div class="scroll-content">
<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javscript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //scrollpane parts
    var scrollPane = $( ".scroll-pane"),
        scrollContent = $(".scroll-content");

    //build slider
    var scrollbar = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            if ( scrollContent.width() > scrollPane.width() ) {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", Math.round(
                    ui.value / 100 * ( scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width() )
                ) + "px" );
            } else {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", 0 );
            }
        }

    });

    //append icon to handle
    var handleHelper = scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" )
    .mousedown(function() {
        scrollbar.width( handleHelper.width() );
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        scrollbar.width( "100%" );
    })
    .append( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical'></span>" )
    .wrap( "<div class='ui-handle-helper-parent'></div>" ).parent();

    //change overflow to hidden now that slider handles the scrolling
    scrollPane.css( "overflow", "hidden" );

    //size scrollbar and handle proportionally to scroll distance
    function sizeScrollbar() {
        var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
        var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
        var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - ( proportion * scrollPane.width() );
        scrollbar.find( ".ui-slider-handle" ).css({
            width: handleSize,
            "margin-left": -handleSize / 2
        });
        handleHelper.width( "" ).width( scrollbar.width() - handleSize );
    }

    //reset slider value based on scroll content position
    function resetValue() {
        var remainder = scrollPane.width() - scrollContent.width();
        var leftVal = scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) === "auto" ? 0 :
            parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ) );
        var percentage = Math.round( leftVal / remainder * 100 );
        scrollbar.slider( "value", percentage );
    }

    //if the slider is 100% and window gets larger, reveal content
    function reflowContent() {
            var showing = scrollContent.width() + parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 );
            var gap = scrollPane.width() - showing;
            if ( gap > 0 ) {
                scrollContent.css( "margin-left", parseInt( scrollContent.css( "margin-left" ), 10 ) + gap );
            }
    }

    //change handle position on window resize
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        resetValue();
        sizeScrollbar();
        reflowContent();
    });
    //init scrollbar size
    setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
});
</script>
```

I could really use somebody's help figuring out how to just have one of the items scroll and not both.

Thanks